# Why is the ratio thermal noise/temperature constant?

Tags: temperature, biophysics, noise

I understand that more temperature means more molecules hitting each other and therefore more noise. But why is the ratio between the two roughly constant? 
If the temperature doubles, why would its Gaussian distribution also double?

Comment: Please add more specific information. Are you talking about electrical noise of a resistor or something else? What do you mean by a Gaussian distribution doubling? Do you mean it's *width* doubles?

Comment: Yes, I mean why does the width of the distribution double? I was thinking mainly of biological molecules, such as interactions of components of a cascade that leads to a response in a cell, but from what I understand something similar applies to resistors so that would be fine too. But yes, the right way of asking my question would be why does the width of the Gaussian double as the mean doubles. thanks for clarifying

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to understand what's going on would be to go through the random walk problem. Have you seen that? If not, I'd be happy to give a summary.

Comment: If you don't mind a summary would be great. I had a look but it's not obvious to me how it solves this. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a particle floating around in water.
The particle is constantly being hit by the water molecules moving around in thermal motion.
Approximately speaking, at each point in time, the particle gets hit left or right.
Let's simplify and say that each time the particle gets hit, it moves right one unit with probability $p$ or left by one unit with probability $q = 1 - p$.

### Random walk with step size = 1

After $n$ steps, what is the probability distribution of the particle's position?

Let's think about a sequence of $n$ steps that winds up at position $k$.
In order to wind up at position $k$, it must be the case that the number of rightward steps $n_+$ plus the number of leftward steps $n_-$ is equal to $k$:
$$n_+ - n_- = k \, .$$
What's is the probability of getting a *particular* sequence with $n_+$ rightward and $n_-$ leftward steps?
It's $p^{n_+} q^{n_-}$, i.e. multiply by probability $p$ for each rightward step and probability $q$ for each leftward step.

Ok now how many ways can we rearrange this sequence?
There are $n$ elements, so there are $n!$ ways to rearrange it.
However, rearranging the rightward steps among themselves doesn't actually give a new sequence, so we should divide by $n_+!$, and similarly for the leftward steps.

Therefore, the probability $P(k)$ of winding up at position $k$ is
\begin{align}
P(k)
&= p^{n_+} q^{n_-} \frac{n!}{(n_+!) (n_-!)} \\
&= p^{(n+k)/2}q^{(n-k)/2} \frac{n!}{\left( \frac{n+k}{2} \right)! \left( \frac{n-k}{2} \right)!} \, .
\end{align}

This is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).
It has mean $\mu = n(2p - 1)$ and variance $\text{Var} = npq$.

### Step size relation to temperature

> If the temperature doubles, why would its Gaussian distribution also double?

Remember we started with the idea of water molecules whacking into a particle.
Let's ask: how far does the particle go each time it is hit?
First of all, the very fact that we assumed each step is independent means that we implicitly have a system with a lot of friction.
In other words, each time the particle is hit, it gains some speed, moves a bit, but then comes to rest again before the next molecular collision.
This is a good assumption for a lot of real systems that have high friction, like a particle in water.
Ok so how far does the particle go?
Well, Newton says
$$F = ma$$
and in our case, after the collision, the only force is friction $F_\text{friction} = -\gamma \dot{x}$
where $\gamma$ is the coefficient of friction.
Therefore, the equation of motion is
$$ -\gamma \dot{x} = m \ddot{x} $$
or
$$ -\gamma v = m \dot{v}$$
which has solution
$$v(t) = v(0) \exp \left( - \frac{\gamma}{m} t \right) $$
where $v(0)$ is the velocity immediately following the molecular collision.
Integrating this gives the total displacement of the particle resulting from the collision:
$$\Delta x \equiv x(t \rightarrow \infty) = \int_0^\infty v(t) \, dt = \frac{m}{\gamma}v(0) \, . $$

The initial speed $v(0)$ should be related to the kinetic energy $E$ of the molecule by something like $E \propto v(0)^2$ where the exact proportionality depends on the details of the collision geometry, etc.
Therefore, we know that the particle's displacement should be proportional to the square root of the kinetic energy of the surrounding particles.
Since kinetic energy is proportional to temperature, we have

$$\Delta x \propto T^{1/2} \, . $$

If you do a little basic math, you can show that if you scale a variable by a factor $A$, then the variance scales by $A^2$.
Therefore, if we scale our random walk step size by $T^{1/2}$ to account for the true physical size of the step, we find that the variance scales by $T$, which is what we wanted to show.

### Generality of the random walk

We started with the idea of a particle getting bumped around by the surrounding water molecules, but this basic step-left/step-right process shows up all over physics.
The voltage on a resistor is the sum of the voltages from the constituent charged particles, each of which fluctuates around.
The result in that case is [Johnson-Nyquest noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).
Any process that consists of independent left/right steps has the same statistical structure.

If we use some more approximations, we can show that the binomial distribution is approximately Gaussian.
To do it yourself, look up [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and apply it to $P(k)$.

Comment: I just realized that I may have missed a dependence between the mass of the particle and $v(0)$. Will look again later if I remember, but I think the basic arguments are right.

Comment: That's awesome thanks! I'll try to digest this better, but I feel I can ask an extension of the original question at this point: if I have a phenomenon (like a molecule hitting a receptor on a cell) and this activation takes say 50 ms on average with a certain variance (assuming the process has a normal distribution)... if I slow down the process (by cooling for example) to take 150 ms can I assume the variance will also triple? (I guess so, from your explanation above).

Comment: Now, let's say I have a readout (like the cell doing something as a response) and I see that when the activation takes 50 ms, the ability of the cell to distinguish two molecules activating the receptor one after the other 'breaks down' around 20 ms. (let's say that faster than that really can't be distinguished). Instead, when the system is cooled, the ability to distinguish break down at bigger intervals, say 70 ms. Could this be due to the overlap between variances of different sizes? (linked, as you explained, to means of different 'size').

Comment: Could I (tentatively) test this by seeing whether the 'breakdown' correlates in both cases (50 ms and 150 ms) with the amount of overlap between the two variances (of two successive events hitting the receptor)? thanks so much again.

Comment: Hi Daniel, quick question about the end of your previous explanation. you say ' if you scale a variable by a factor A, then the variance scales by A2. Therefore, if we scale our random walk step size by T1/2 to account for the true physical size of the step, we find that the variance scales by T'. Sorry you lost me here. How can variance scale by A squared but then scale by T? If T becomes 4x bigger, does the variance get 4x bigger or 4x4=16 times bigger? (I am thinking the first, but then how do we fit the A squared reasoning?). I bet it's very banal but I'm lost. thanks

Comment: @matteoeoeo variance goes as the square of the step size. Step size goes as $T^{1/2}$. Therefore variance goes as $T$. Does that clear it up?

Comment: thanks @DanielSank I'm still regurgitating this whole thing but the answer was great.

Comment: Can I ask one small additional question? Is what you described above essentially a Poisson distribution? Or is it at least a property of Poisson distributions? thanks

Comment: @matteoeoeo Poisson and binomial distributions are related. A Poisson distribution is just an approximation of a particular case of the binomial (I'm pretty sure).